# Faster alternatives to groupby and aggregation in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a collection of reports that may be categorised in multiple different ways. I'm trying to obtain the top keywords based on TF-IDF for different possible combinations of grouping for these reports. I'm using a groupby() function for all of the different combinations, however, pandas's groupby() gets very slow when the number of reports and categories is large. Here's a sample of the code that I'm using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple'],
                   'cat2': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                   'cat3': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'cat4': ['i', 'ii', 'ii', 'iii', 'i', 'i'],
                   'cat5': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red'],
                   'Reports': [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'], ['pqr'], ['stu','vwx'], ['yz','ab','cd'], ['ef','gh']]})

categories = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3','cat4','cat5']
groups = [list(combo) for combo in combinations(categories, 2)]

for group in groups:
    df1 = df.groupby([group[0], group[1]], as_index=False).agg({'Reports':'sum'})
    # Some other functions to process df1 to get top keywords
```

I've seen some other suggestions on alternatives to groupby on stackoverflow, however, they mainly uses numpy arrays to process numerical data. I have a list of strings here instead, what are some alternatives that I can use for faster processing?

Answer (score 0):

> number of(...)categories is large

Consider following feature of [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

> The number of items returned is `n! / r! / (n-r)!` when `0 <= r <= n`
> or zero when `r > n`.

where n is number of items in iterable, r is 2nd argument to `itertools.combinations`. So in your particular case of `combinations(categories, 2)` said number is

```
n! / 2! / (n-2)!
```

which is equal to

```
n! / (n-2)! / 2!
```

which is equal to

```
n * (n-1) / 2!
```

which is equal to

```
n * (n-1) / 2
```

So propotions of time consumption would be 45 for n=10, 4950 for n=100, 499500 for n=1000 and so on. Whilst this is not solution that might show you how much of speed-up you need to achieve.

> (...)arrays to process numerical data. I have a list of strings here
> instead(...)

Note that if you know all allowed values of string *a priori* then you might easily assign number to each value (decorate), then process your data, then change number back to string (undecorate)

Answer (score 0):

You can build generate an ad-hoc aggregate function and collect all the aggregations in one pass (I must confess -- [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) is a library of mine):

```py
from itertools import combinations

import pandas as pd

from convtools import conversion as c


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "cat1": ["apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "banana", "apple"],
        "cat2": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"],
        "cat3": ["x", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"],
        "cat4": ["i", "ii", "ii", "iii", "i", "i"],
        "cat5": ["red", "blue", "green", "green", "blue", "red"],
        "Reports": [
            ["abc", "def"],
            ["ghi", "jkl", "mno"],
            ["pqr"],
            ["stu", "vwx"],
            ["yz", "ab", "cd"],
            ["ef", "gh"],
        ],
    }
)

categories = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5"]
groups = [list(combo) for combo in combinations(categories, 2)]


# generate aggregate function
converter = c.aggregate(
    {
        # there will be as many reducers as combinations
        (key1, key2): c.ReduceFuncs.DictArray(
            (c.item(key1), c.item(key2)),  # key
            c.item("Reports")  # value
        )
        for key1, key2 in combinations(categories, 2)
    }
).gen_converter()

converter(df.to_dict("records"))

# In [39]: converter(df.to_dict("records"))
# Out[39]:
# {('cat1',
#   'cat2'): defaultdict(None,
#              {('apple', 'a'): [['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno']],
#               ('banana', 'b'): [['pqr'], ['stu', 'vwx']],
#               ('banana', 'c'): [['yz', 'ab', 'cd']],
#               ('apple', 'c'): [['ef', 'gh']]}),
#  ('cat1',
#   'cat3'): defaultdict(None,
#              {('apple', 'x'): [['abc', 'def']],
#               ('apple', 'y'): [['ghi', 'jkl', 'mno'], ['ef', 'gh']],
#               ('banana', 'x'): [['pqr'], ['yz', 'ab', 'cd']],
#               ('banana', 'y'): [['stu', 'vwx']]}),
#  ...
```

If you can replace the input dataframe with an iterable of dicts, please do so. Should you have any clarification on what further processing you need (e.g. taking unique "reports" or anything else), let me know, I'll do my best adjust the example.